# How can i get a dictionary use re.match() and re.groupdict() with a complex regex?

Tags: python, regex

I kind of wish select the domain name from string and put it into a dictionary. So i use `re.match()` and `re.groupdict()` on this string:

```
Location: hk USER: Will Lee PASS: 1234 INFO: www.hotmail.com
```

The code is

```
re.match(r"(?P<Domain>\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+?)\.(?=com))",str).groupdict()
```

This should make a dictionary which key is "Domain" and value is "hotmail", but somehow it returned:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: That pattern doesn't `match` the whole string, try `re.search(...).groupdict()`.

Comment: And also he needs to correct the pattern .

Comment: Avoid variable names like 'str', which will obscure the actual Python str type, and even worse, confuse those trying to maintain your code some time in the future.

Comment: I change my pattern and use `re.search()` method.And it worked! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.search` instead of `re.match` because match tries to find the text from the start. And also you need to give the dot inside the lookahead which asserts capture one or more alphanumeric characters followed by the string `.com`

```
>>> re.search(r'(?P<Domain>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=\.com)', s).groupdict()
{'Domain': 'hotmail'}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use re.match with (?P<..dict key...>) and groupdict().
code:

```
import re
s="Location: hk USER: Will Lee PASS: 1234 INFO: www.hotmail.com"
yourDict = re.match(r"^Location: (?P<Location>\w+?) USER: (?P<User>.+?(?= PASS: .+? INFO: .+$)) PASS: (?P<Pass>.+?(?= INFO: .+$)) INFO: (?P<Doman>.+$)",s).groupdict()
```

=> {'User': 'Will Lee', 'Doman': 'www.hotmail.com', 'Location': 'hk', 'Pass': '1234'}